# Action to start when PopUp IsOpen is set to true

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8, popup

I'm making an app using the MVVM model for windows phone 8 and wish to invoke a action when my PopUp Isopen is set to true. I've seen the for WPF you can do this through style.Triggers, but apparently Silverlight doesn't support this. Is there a way to start an Action or Event when I set the PopUp IsOpen to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a background task in the popup that will perform some code, and can quit after the code has run, is that what you wish? Or using loaded event?

Comment: Using the loaded event helper. I ended setting the eventtrigger t loaded

Answer (score 0):

Simply data bind a `bool` property to the `Popup.IsOpen` property:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}" ... />
```

When the `Popup` control is opened, program execution will go to the property setter. You can do what you like there in response.

```
public bool IsPopupOpen
{
    get { return isPopupOpen; }
    set
    {
        isPopupOpen = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPopupOpen");
        if (isPopupOpen)
        {
            // Do something in response to the opened popup here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm allready doing it somewhat like that, but the class I'm binding to which I use for the popup is an portable class library. So is it still possible to make an behaviour when it is set? I've also made a viewmodel for the popup. Is it possible to do it here?

Comment: see the above comment